# Minimum comparisons for sorting by comparison sort

Tags: sorting, compare

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list) that we need minimum log(n!) comparisons to sort n elements using any type of comparison sort, as we get maximum 2^n cases which should be greater than n! (the number of permutations). I just don't understand this line, how can t comparisons lead to 2^t cases. Example, when I do 3 comparisons let's say I get 1 > 2, 3<5, 6>9, how am I getting 8 cases?

Comment: The lower bound for the number of comparisons in a comparison sort is n*log(n). See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/proving-the-lower-bound-of-compares-in-comparison-based-sorting. Where do you get the idea that there are 2^n cases?

Comment: @JimMischel i read it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Answer (score 0):

How can `t` comparisons lead to `2^t` cases?

If you view it as a decision tree, as shown in the link I provided in my comment, it becomes more clear.

A single comparison provides two cases:

```
    (a < b)
true       false
```

With three items, you end up with:

```
                      (a < b)
          (a < c)                 (a < c)
    (b < c)     (b < c)     (b < c)     (b < c)
   1       2   3       4   5       6   7       8
```

As you can see, each comparison results in two branches. There are eight possible paths through the tree. Each of the leaf nodes represents an outcome.